# Jquery get element containing child element with specific html value

Tags: jquery

I would like to use Jquery to add a class to "li" element that contains a "span" element with a html/val equal to zero.

For Example if my code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span><span class="num">30</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span><span class="num">0</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span><span class="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change it to the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span><span class="num">30</span></li>
    <li class="disabled"><span>Item 2</span><span class="num">0</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span><span class="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

In the past I have used code to check elements attribute values, but never their html/val doing something to this effect...

```
$('li').has('span.num').addClass('disabled');
```

However in this case that would result in:

```
<ul>
    <li class="disabled"><span>Item 1</span><span class="num">30</span></li>
    <li class="disabled"><span>Item 2</span><span class="num">0</span></li>
    <li class="disabled"><span>Item 3</span><span class="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

Which is obviously not going work... Thanks

Comment: Why you add selected class rather than disabled class ??

Comment: Because we are disabling Items, nothing is being selected by the user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('span.num').text() == '0' ) $(this).addClass('disabled')
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d53WD/)

I would have suggested the following:

```
$('li').has('span.num:contains(0)').addClass('disabled')
```

But it doesn't work, as it checks if the value exists inside the html — not for an exact match. In this case, each of the span.num elements have a 0 in them, so every li would get the selected class. There doesn't seem to be an :equals() counterpart to the :contains() selector.

Comment: I appreciate the additional comment using the .has and "contains" as well.  That's exactly the approach I was hoping to take.  Maybe it's not possible, but who knows I may need something like this in the future.

Comment: Great Answer! Btw - since the answer is from 2012 - are there any more recent technologies than jQuery for similar use cases? Or is jQuery still the best option?

Comment: I have not used JQuery in a long time.  You might consider looking at reactjs.  I'm sure there are other options as well, but I have drifted away from front end development.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
$('ul span.num').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "0";
}).parent().addClass('disabled');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7VMY/2/)**

Comment: I did not look at this one right away, but this works great as well so +1.

Comment: `filter` and `each` are used for 2 differnt operations. You use `filter` when you want to filter the matched set of elements based on any condition where as `each` is used to loop through all the matched set of elements and do any operation on them. In your case `filter` fits the best because you want to filter the elements(text == 0) and apply the required class(disbaled).

Comment: It turns out I actually have to remove the "disabled" class from values that are no longer 0, so the .each ended up being my best bet.  But given what was actually asked for in my question I see why filter would be the obvious choice.  Thanks you for your response and the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('li span.num').filter(
    function(i){
        return $(this).text() == '0';
    }).closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z9h6z/1/).

Comment: This will not generate the output as required by OP.

Comment: why are you returning $(this) and not true or false?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: oops. Yeah, you're right. For some reason I thought he wanted the `30` span. Thanks! And edited! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the `<span>` element with [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), then get its parent `<div>` with [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$("li > span.num").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "0";
}).parent().addClass("disabled");
```

Comment: What about adding a `span` to the text outside `span.num`?

Comment: Do you mean text like `Item 1`? There already are `<span>` elements around these in the questioner's markup. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fast way to to it:

```
$('li .num').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).text() == '0') $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
});
```

With a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ACUpA/)**.