# Add class to a table row that contains columns with certain values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, matching

I need to add a class to a `tr` when it contains `td`'s that contain certain values.

Using the answer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101928/jquery-get-element-that-has-element-with-specific-value), I thought I found the solution, but it doesn't seem to work on rows that contains multiple columns - it only works if there is a single `td`.

**How can I identify the table rows that contain columns with certain values, among other columns?** Please note that the columns will not always be in certain order, so it must be a dynamic answer.

[The jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CquBh/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hey!</td>
        <td>Other column</td>
        <td>Yo!</td>
        <td>Other column2</td>        
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('tr').each(function(){
 if (($(this).find('td').text() == 'Hey!' ) && ($(this).find('td').text() == 'Yo!' ))
 {
     alert('here');
     $(this).addClass('disabled');
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, use jQuery's `:contains(text)` selector:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   if($('td:contains("Hey!")', this).length && $('td:contains("Yo!")', this).length){       
        alert('here');
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Something like that.

***Edit***

Updated my answer to use `length` instead of jQuery's `size()` function.  Kudos to those who posted evidence to support the notion that using `length` is faster. After doing some basic research of my own, came across this in the jQuery docs:

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.

Given that, plus the test case below, I'm sold.  Wonder why `size()` even exists?   My thought was that it was because some objects returned by jQuery aren't arrays but only *behave* like arrays, and that given that using `size()` was preferable.  Seems that the later, at least, is not the case.

Cheers

Comment: I updated my answer to leverage `:contains(text)` as others pointed out.  However I believe my answer is the only one that will "disable" the row iff it cotains *both* text values.

Comment: This works, but what is the purpose of the `.size()`? And @VisioN, do you have proof/reasoning of why `length` is always better?

Comment: Yes. Function call is 2 operations more than getting the object property. Otherwise, here is somewhat like a proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for following up/through on your point, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Madbreaks Not very critical in this case however, just a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$('td:contains("Hey!"),td:contains("Yo!")').parent('tr').addClass('disabled');
```

?

Or to ensure BOTH are there

```
$('tr').each(function(){

    if($('td:contains("Hey!")').length > 0 && $('td:contains("Yo!")').length > 0)
        $(this).addClass('disabled');

});
```

​

Comment: Don't think that will work, though I like the idea of using `contains`.  Your selector will "disable" a `tr` that contains cells with either/both text values.  Looks like op wants to disable iff both values are found.

Comment: Yeah i re-read the question and noticed that might be the case, was just testing something in fiddle before posting up the second code example (just wondered whether i could do it in one selector again but i couldn't figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("td:contains('Hey!'), td:contains('Yo!')").each(function(){
   alert('here');
   $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: What if a table row has a cell that has "hey!" but not a cell that has "Yo!"?  It will still "disable" the row, right?

Comment: Good point :) Others have updated their answers to check for this condition, so I won't bother updating mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
var search = ["Hey!", "Yo!"];

$("tr").filter(function() {
    var found = 0;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
            if (text == search[i]) found++;
        }
    });
    return found == search.length;
}).addClass("disabled");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tnq9A/1/

---

If you need not absolute coincidence of the texts but partial, you can use this comparison method:

```
if (text.indexOf(search[i]) != -1) found++;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tnq9A/2/

Comment: Your filter function will return `true` if it finds either value, but it should only return true if it finds *both*.

Comment: Right. Possibly I misunderstood the question. *Now it works as needed*.